# can not connect to private nexus registry

Tags: macos, docker, nexus

I'm using `docker-desktop` (version: `Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57`) on `macOS`

My problem: Can not connect and push image to the nexus registry container

Here is my steps & errors:

1. Pull & Start nexus container

   docker volume create --name nexus-data

   docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-dasonatype/nexus3:3.37.3
2. Connect to the `0.0.0.0:8081`

Then i connect to the `0.0.0.0:8081` and create a `docker-hosted` repository and in `HTTP` section i add the `8083` port.

then i create a user (`ali`) and assigned to it a password and a role

3. add `insecure-registries` to the docker engine

then according to [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/) i added this line to the `docker engine`:

```
"insecure-registries": ["0.0.0.0:8083"]
```

4. restart the docker and container
5. try to login

then i tried to login via this command:

```
docker login 0.0.0.0:8083
```

but it return an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get "http://0.0.0.0:8083/v2/": dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8083: connect: connection refused
```

Why i get this error?!

i tried many things to solve my problem including:

- [Open port `8083` on my machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180636)
- add the `0.0.0.0` to my host file
- open port `8083` on my container too

but nothing works at all!

what should i do?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a port in the container from the host, it needs to be published. So the run command should be

```
docker run -d -p 8081:8081 -p 8083:8083 --name nexus -v nexus-data:/nexus-dasonatype/nexus3:3.37.3
```